# How to hide this error on vstest.console.exe?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, testing, visual-studio-2013, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have developed unit test project and executed it with

```
vstest.console.exe
```

In that console i just want to show method pass or method fail..

how to hide the errors , trace ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) are the available command line options for `vstest.console.exe`, none of them does exactly what you need.

Your best bet is to write a custom logger by implementing `ITestLogger` from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll` and then specifying it with `/logger` option.

Check [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vikramagrawal/archive/2012/07/26/writing-loggers-for-command-line-test-runner-vstest-console-exe.aspx) for more details.